# Why it doesn't enter to the condition

Tags: javascript

```
let search_field = document.querySelector(".search-field input");
let all_friends = document.querySelectorAll(".chat .profile-name");

search_field.onchange = function() {
    let search_value = search_field.value.toLowerCase();
    let sp_search_value = search_value.split("");
    
    for (let i = 0; i < all_friends.length; i++)
    {
        for (let y = 0; y < sp_search_value.length; y++) {
            // Why it doesn't Enter to this condition even if field is empty?,
            // But if I make it outside the nested loop it works!?
            if (search_value == "") {
                console.log("Empty");
            }

            // To search even if user did'nt enter the full name
            else if (sp_search_value[y] == all_friends[i].textContent[y].toLowerCase()) {
                // Show chats if the field is empty or if exisits after remove them all
                all_friends[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove("disabled");
            }
            // Disabled if not exists
            else if (search_value != all_friends[i].textContent.toLowerCase()) {
                let grandEle = all_friends[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
                grandEle.classList.add("disabled");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is if I make it outside the nested loop it works!?
the problem in the nested loop but what is it?

Comment: Because when `search_value` is empty, `sp_search_value` becomes zero, and the `y` loop will never be entered. Place the condition before the second loop, then it logs the emptys.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slighty shorter version demonstrating how it can be done with `Array.prototype.every()`:

```js
let search_field = document.querySelector(".search-field input");
let all_friends = document.querySelectorAll(".chat .profile-name");

search_field.oninput = function() {
    let search_value = search_field.value.toLowerCase();
    let sp_search_value = search_value.split(" ");
    
    all_friends.forEach((f,i)=>{
      f.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display=
      sp_search_value.every(v=>f.textContent.indexOf(v)>-1) ? "" : "none" 
    })
}
```

```html
<div class="search-field">
    <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="chat">
    <div>an unaffected header</div>
    <div class="profile-top">1<div><div><div class="profile-name">apple orange banana</div></div></div></div>
    <div class="profile-top">2<div><div><div class="profile-name">grapefruit blueberry pear</div></div></div></div>
    <div class="profile-top">3<div><div><div class="profile-name">raisin date</div></div></div></div>
    <div class="profile-top">4<div><div><div class="profile-name">pear apple</div></div></div></div>
    <div class="profile-top">5<div><div><div class="profile-name">orange satsuma lemon</div></div></div></div>
    <div>and an unaffected footer</div>
</div>
```

At present my mode of comparison is slightly more relaxed than yours: it will show profiles as soon as their `.textContent`s contain the entered search words as fragments. This can of course be changed to something stricter if required.

Moving up the DOM hierarchy using `.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode` is not a good idea as it might easily break as soon as you change the structure of your markup. Something like `.closest(".profile-top")` would be more stable. But this requires a change of the HTML (see my example above).